# Putting new blade on 1940's table saw

Tags: table-saw

I recently purchased a 1940's Craftsman table saw off Craigslist, I think it's a model 103.0213 ([manual here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1189180/Craftsman-103-0213.html#manual)).  I've been stripping the rust off of it, revamping the electrical for the switch, all sorts of stuff to make it safer and usable, and I've come to the blade.  Here's a picture of it:
[image]

The blade looks like it's 7.5", and not in terrible shape (but I'd still love to replace it with a new one).  From what I've read online, [some people have trouble getting new blades to fit](https://www.finewoodworking.com/forum/old-craftsman-table-saw-1940s-1-2).  I'll be honest though, I get kinda lost in the lingo of their descriptions. I apologize for my helplessness on that. Would somebody please explain to me in plain English how to put a newer saw blade on?  And obviously I'm looking for safe(r) and new, but at the same time I'm just a weekend hobbyist so I'm also looking for fairly economical.

Comment: Oh, I'd add that while that blade isn't in "bad shape" in that it hasn't rusted through, I'd guess that it would cut like butter through a hot knife (not like a hot knife through butter). It may be salvageable by cleaning the rust off and attempting to sharpen it yourself, but personally, I'd only use it as a learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer was perfect and I've already purchased a new blade and a handful of the mcmaster adaptor's you linked.

Comment: The manual for that saw indicates it's 8": https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1189180/Craftsman-103-0213.html#manual

Comment: Ooh! Good find, @DaveD!

Comment: Joe, I know you're on the path to replacing the saw blade but just to mention, it's rarely/never, a good idea to try to salvage an old blade like this because saw technology has come a long, long way since the 1940s. Plus, sharpening them well is a skill that takes some practice, and doing it poorly results in poor cuts at minimum, and could add stress to a mechanism that doesn't it (age, unknown amount of previous use). As noted you might keep the old blade as a memento/possible future sale item, but the steel itself has potential uses as a raw material, e.g. for scrapers or scratch stocks.

Comment: While @Graphus makes some good points, this looks like a pretty simple blade with simple tooth geometry. It would be easy to sharpen this assuming the hook isn't completely warn down (I can't quite tell from the photo). If the teeth are reasonably evenly worn, and there is some hook left, it would make a decent util blade for things like sawing knotty stuff or interrupted cuts.

Comment: @jdv, I might agree except look at one tooth at left, first "full" tooth above the square. And two of the teeth right at bottom look like there's less of them left, especially the one directly under 5 5/8" on the rule. Moot point because of those teeth, but re. sharpening, isn't it like a lot of sharpening — it's easy if you've done it before and have gotten decent at it, but not at all if you've never done anything like it previously? I fancy myself an above-average sharpener and I'm not sure I'd want to do it manually, even if I built myself a sharpening jig specifically to tackle it.

Comment: @Graphus, I've had very good luck just honing the outside of the tooth, and maybe a few swipes square along the inside. Like I said, I like to keep a few all-tool-steel blades around for work where carbide might be less suited. I don't think I could use this photo to determine if this blade was a good candidate for that. At this resolution, a few pixel interpolation could make any point look strange. My suggestion is, if it is in decent shape, keep it around just in case -- either for making other tools or for situations where you don't want to ruin your fave carbide toothed blade.

Comment: @jdv, I do take your point about all-steel blades and how they might be preferable to use versus a carbide-toothed one for certain jobs, but re. the *at this resolution* thing, did you click on the image to see it at full size? On my monitor the blade is about 14" across... ^_^

Comment: @Graphus, oh heh. I _never_ click on the image links. I sort of see now where it looks like it hit a nail or something, though because of JPEG artefacting I can't quite make out the geometry of the tooth very well from the foreground smutz. But if those teeth actually look like that, then this looks like a candidate for the metal scrap for turning into other tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To define the lingo:

- **Arbor** is the threaded shaft that comes out of the motor onto which the saw blade is mounted.
- **Arbor Washer** goes around the arbor, just like the saw blade does, but is much smaller in diameter than the blade and doesn't have any teeth. Some saws have a washer on each side of the blade, some only have one on the "outside" of the blade (away from the motor).
- **Arbor Nut** goes onto the arbor after the blade and washer have gone on. This gets tightened down (often is a reverse, or left-hand thread) to hold the blade in place. Do note: It's been a while since I've changed a table saw blade, so I may be confusing that with my miter saw arbor nut threading.

  - Since you seem to have a good view of the threads, look to see if they if they're regular or reverse thread. If they're reverse, you'll drive yourself nuts trying to loosen with "righty-tighty, lefty-loosey" since it would be "lefty-tighty, righty-loosey.
- **Blade** that's the sharp, round, spinny thing that separates fingers from hands. (Said tongue-in-cheek - but if you didn't know that, please step away from the saw, now.)

At the link you provided, it looks like the major issue is that this saw has a 1/2" arbor and most modern 7 1/4" circular saw blades (which is probably what you'd need to use - you'd probably have to search long and hard to find 7 1/2" blades, if that is actually the measurement) are designed for a 5/8" arbor. If you put a modern blade on there, it'll be a sloppy fit with that extra 1/8" of play. Sure, you could crank the arbor nut down in an attempt to hold the blade in place, but with the torque applied to the blade when it hits wood, I wouldn't count on it holding safely. Even if it did, I wouldn't count on a nice, true cut from it. And, when you put the blade on, all the extra 1/8" of room would be at the bottom since gravity will be on and it will pull the blade down so the arbor hole sits on the arbor itself. Once you've got it tightened down, you fire up the saw and the blade bounces as it spins out of round - not exactly a safe situation, either.

Therefore, you'll need an adapter to accommodate a modern blade with a 5/8" arbor. I hit up my favorite internet search engine with

> saw arbor adapter 1/2 5/8

and came up with a variety of options.

There was this post at the [Bob Vila forum](https://www.bobvila.com/posts/42058-1-2-to-5-8-arbor-adapter) (from 2005) that has several on-line references and a recommendation to cut a thin piece of copper tubing to use as a bushing. (I'm not sure I'd go with that one, see cautions above).

There were a *wide* variety of arbor adapters to allow blades with a 1" arbor to work on a 5/8" arbor - make sure you avoid those, that's not the adaptation you're after.

Many of the adapters I found seem to be for hole saws and angle grinders, so without making any recommendation (and at the risk of being down-voted for providing shopping info) I'll list a couple of options, just to ensure you're on the right track:

- [McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com/68885A64/)

  - this one is a ring that fits within the saw blade itself (makes the copper pipe adapter seem more reasonable, though this one is steel).

  - you'd need a handful for different blades, or to carefully transfer this one to each different blade you're going to use.
- [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0052IP99C)

  - This one threads onto the arbor and gives you a new arbor diameter with new threads for a different arbor nut.

  - A new arbor nut should be fairly easy to find as that *seems* to be the modern standard. I'd suggest taking your adapter in to your local hardware store and ask to borrow the arbor nut off of one or two of their table saws to ensure the threading is correct, then purchase a replacement arbor nut from them.
  - Keep the old one off your Craftsman as a souvenir/for authenticity (you never know when it'll become a collector's item).
  - If I went with an adapter like this, I'd put some thread locker on between the old arbor and the adapter, just to help keep it in place while tightening and loosening the arbor nut. Essentially, it becomes part of the tool.

Comment: Nice one! +2 if I could.

Comment: *"and at the risk of being down-voted for providing shopping info"* FWIW I've never noticed downvotes for providing shopping options (and I certainly don't do it myself). Different to asking for them which is frowned upon generally, and against community rules of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance, @Graphus, and for fixing my typos.

Comment: Go with the bushing. The adapter from Amazon is for hole saws, not table saws. Table saw arbors typically have ACME threads, not the triangular threads that the Amazon adapter appears to have, so a) it might not thread onto the saw, and b) if it does, a normal 5/8" arbor nut won't fit. Adapter bushings only cost a few bucks each, so they won't be a big expense even if you buy one for every blade you have plus a few extra.